# How can I enable my fingerprint reader while Windows is unlocked and find out when it's touched?

Tags: windows-10, fingerprint

I bought a fingerprint reader, and it works great for unlocking my PC, but I'd like to *lock* it with the same gesture. Is there any way I can make my reader respond to input while Windows is unlocked and somehow find out when input has been registered? For this use case, I don't need to determine if the finger used is valid for authentication -- only whether or not the sensor has been touched. From there, a simple `rundll32.exe user32.dll, LockWorkStation` would get me where I want to go.

Comment: What's version of Window 10? Based on my known Windows hello only support fingerprint identification. No gesture available for lock and unlock computer.

Comment: Fingerprint readers are used for authentication within a session, not just login. Implementing the feature you want would negate this functionality and it would be a nightmare, locking the session whenever a user touches it inadvertently.

Comment: These are some really strange responses. I understand that this functionality isn't built into Windows -- that's why I'm here asking for a workaround. I also understand there may be downsides to what I'm asking for, but I'm not running a business and this isn't Server Fault -- this is for me, I want it, and that's why I requested it.

Comment: Well, feature requests should be directed to manufacturers (drivers/software) and/or the OS devs (Microsoft). I merely explained (tried to) why such feature doesn't exist, why it doesn't even make sense and what would be the implications of implementing it.

Comment: Also there's a shortcut already to easily lock the screen: Windows key + L (just like the current Ubuntu or any other distro with Gnome DE). I really don't understand why someone would want to touch a fingerprint reader instead of a simple and easy to remember (L = "Lock") shortcut, honestly.

Comment: You need to use a specialized app. Have a look for example at [Zapier](https://zapier.com/).